# Xquery - Appending attribute to all tuples

Tags: xquery

I hope you all are doing very well.

I am a bit stuck with a problem in Xquery.

## Background to the problem

I have been doing a homework in xquery where I am supossed to generate a recursive function that starts in a country and then recursively calls the bordering countries and so on. For example, in my exercise we start in Sweden, so the **first** call will generate the following code:

```
<country name="Norway"/>
<country name="Finland"/>
```

For the **second** call we get this data along with a tuple for Russia (since Russia borders Finland). For the **third** call we get a whole host of countries (that borders Russia).

I have finally managed to get the recursion functioning, and I have managed to get the countries to be generated as described above.

However, there is one thing that is missing and that is the amount of steps it takes to get to each country. I have a variable for this but I awkwardly can't seem to get it to work.

## Problem description

I have a variable called *$borderingCountries* which holds the following data:

```
<name>Norway</name>
<name>Finland</name>
```

Also I have a variable called *$step* which has the value of 1. I want to insert this as an attribute for the tuples in *$borderingCountries*, ideally I would like to make it so that my *$borderingCountries* looks something like this:

```
  <name steps = 1> Norway </name>
  <name steps = 1> Finland </name>
```

Where steps is the value of *$step*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your code. The problem description is helpful, but it's difficult to suggest how to modify your code to achieve the desired outcome without seeing it.

Comment: Alright, I understand. I will be thinking about this in future posts. I appreciate the effort, thanks and take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the elements and want to "add" an attribute you need to recreate them with the wanted attribute

```
let $steps := 1,
    $countries := (<name>Norway</name>, <name>Finland</name>)
return $countries!<name steps="{$steps}">{data()}</name>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Y5

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted to do. I eventually got the program as a whole to function as intended due to this small fix. It was really helpful to me. Thanks! 

I have one Quick question though, what does the exclamation mark do?

Take care.

Comment: The exclamation mark is an operator introduced in XPath/XQuery 3 https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-map-operator that allows more compact and more flexible expressions than doing `for $country in $countries return <name steps="{$steps}">{data($country)}</name>`.  It is admittedly more cryptic if you don't know it but in my view a rather handy tool to construct new sequences.